# Isolate html content from rest of site

Tags: html, css

I am developing a system that almost acts as a web based email client.  It's a support desk system.  The system displays emails that are received; think of a web based email client.  Now my issue is that there is horrible Microsoft Word formatted style metadata that is affecting the rest of the application.

I have tried iframes but adjusting the hight to the content is just not working well; and I don't really want to use an iframe.

What pattern or practice can I use to isolate the email html that is presented on the front end so that it doesn't affect the rest of the app?  I mean, how would a Gmail, Yahoo Mail, support desk or CRM system do this?

Comment: Is it the HTML that is affecting your site, or is it inline CSS that is messing up the remainder of the document?

Comment: Except including the source in an iframe, or super-sanitizing the output (eliminating most of the HTML attributes and CSS properties, which is what webmail apps do) i don't think there is a way to do this.

Comment: You could wrap your own code, so you can style with `.my_wrapper .my_class`. Then the mail style does not affect your 'own stuff'.

Comment: Can you parse the contents of the email and rewrite them in your own markup? This might be possible if they follow a set format.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways - I had the same issue when developing a sharepoint site, by the way, as the master styles were effecting my styles and I had no access to the master pages.

1. Wrap your code, and use ID selectors to narrow down the elements you need to style
2. Use `!important` - I do not recommend this method as it's not a best practice

**Example HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <p class="email-par">Some text</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper .email-par{
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

So, even if there are other styles effecting the `<p>` tags on your site, the email paragraphs will take on the styles above.

Answer (score -1):

Use strong ids on your html, then create a CSS file for your email stuff. I recommend you to use !important if some SharePoint style still override your styles

Once you have your own CSS file copy it with SharePoint designer to the master page gallery (_catalogs/mastrpage)

Call it on the header zone of your master page like the example below

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<%$SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/bindtuning.css%>" runat="server" after="SharepointCssFile" />
```

Comment: `!important` is bad mojo, it defeats the "cascade" of cascading stylesheets, and makes styling a site a hundred times more difficult.